# Excel 2010 Open in new instance DDE disabled

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, dde

I have enabled "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)" so that when I open an excel file it opens a new instance, however that file is not loaded.

I then have to open the file in excel either through the "File" menu or by dragging the file into the appropriate instance.

Is there a way around this, where files will open but always in a new instance?

edit ->

I want to have a new instance of excel opened:

- with the contents of the file displayed (i.e. not blank)
- when I double left click the file in explorer.exe
- when I right click open the file in explorer.exe

Disabling DDE was recommended on the MS website to achieve the new instance when opening the files through explorer.exe, but the contents of that file are not displayed - the excel windows is blank.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem:

"works only when you use the Excel icon to open the application. If you use File Open within the Excel application or double-click a file in Windows Explorer, the files will still open in the same instance "